# Vagrant: "The box you're attempting to add already exists"

Tags: vagrant

I am pretty new to Vagrant and already I seem to have hit a snag with it. I am basically following their get started guide.

When I type the command:

> $ vagrant box add hashicorp/precise64

I get this error:

> The box you're attempting to add already exists. Remove it before
>   adding it again or add it with the `--force` flag.
>
> Name: hashicorp/precise64
>   Provider: virtualbox
>   Version: 1.1.0

#### Here is what I have tried.

I destroyed it first using:

> $ vagrant destroy

I then backed out into documents using:

> $ cd -

I then removed the director with:

> $ rm -rf vagrant_getting_started

Then I created a new directory with:

> $ mkdir vagrant_getting_started

I then went into that directory with:

> $ cd vagrant_getting_started

Then I typed:

> $ vagrant box add hashicorp/precise64

Which gave me:

> ==> box: Loading metadata for box 'hashicorp/precise64'
>       box: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/hashicorp/precise64
>   This box can work with multiple providers! The providers that it
>   can work with are listed below. Please review the list and choose
>   the provider you will be working with.
>
> 1) hyperv
>
> 2) virtualbox
>
> 3) vmware_fusion
>
> Enter your choice:

Finally I chose option 2 and then this is where the error is.

Can anyone see anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: you already got that box installed, so why are you trying to add it again, default box location for Mac/linux systems is ~/.vagrant.d/boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the Vagrant box image has become corrupted, you don't need to download it again to re-use it.

Vagrant only downloads the boxes it *doesn't* have. Once a box image is saved locally on your system, Vagrant will use the local image to work from.

When setting up a new Vagrant based project, the following will happen:

- You create or navigate to your project directory
- Run `vagrant init hashicorp/precise64`. This will initialise Vagrant inside the directory, and create a new Vagrantfile if one doesn't exist. It also tells Vagrant which box image to use. If the box image is already stored locally - it won't download it.
- Alternatively, if you already have a Vagrantfile in your project directory, simply run `vagrant up`. Vagrant will take care of everything for you - including downloading the box image (if applicable).

Comment: Ok, you get the point :). What happened is: I did not know the command I was using was adding a new box to the list. I assumed it was creating the environment for me to use. What I actually wanted was the `vagrant init` command. My misunderstanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**vagrant box remove -f laravel/homestead** will remove the "laravel/homestead" from your machine and you can reinstall the same by **vagrant box add laravel/homestead**.